# Analyzing longitudinal data with deaths

Tags: panel-data, missing-data, mnar

I've been given some longitudinal data of animals given different glioblastoma treatments. In addition to conventional survival analysis, they want to look at animal weights and sizes of tumors along time. Of course, animals die through this process. How could I validly analyze this data, especially if it is likely that death would, by eliminating the sickest animals, influence the mean values for the outcome variables of the remaining animals? I think I need to presume that the data is NMAR/MNAR, since missingness (death) is a direct effect of tumor progression.

Comment: There are "joint model" methods that combine mixed models for longitudinal variables along with survival analysis on the same individuals. See [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=joint%20model%20survival&searchOn=3). [Dimitris Rizopoulos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/219012/dimitris-rizopoulos), an expert in that field, frequently contributes to this site.

Comment: Thank you, now I am running into error after error with the JM package. I keep gettting "'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list". The data already is a data.frame.

Comment: I don't do that type of joint modeling myself, I just know that it can be useful in this scenario. Coding-specific questions are off-topic on this site. Make sure first that you can get the examples for the `jointModel()` function to work.